# Return only one object from filtered Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a registration form where the user should enter the date of birth.

But I am confused at a point. Why the below code returns array of 12 objects?

```js
let months= [
      {month: 'January', days: 31},
      {month: 'February', days: 28},
      {month: 'March', days: 31},
      {month: 'April', days: 30},
      {month: 'May', days: 31},
      {month: 'June', days: 30},
      {month: 'July', days: 31},
      {month: 'August', days: 31},
      {month: 'September', days: 30},
      {month: 'October', days: 31},
      {month: 'November', days: 30},
      {month: 'December', days: 31}
];

month = 'April';

let a = Array.from(months, (value, index) =>value);

let b = a.filter(value => {
  return value.month = month;
});
console.log(b);
```

I just wanted `{month: 'April', days: 30}` but the program instead returns 12 objects with different days. Please help.

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` or `===` for comparison.

Comment: The condition should be `value.month === month;` instead of `value.month = month;` `=` is assignment.

Comment: LOL! @HassanImam thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use find in the array

```
let months= [
      {month: 'January', days: 31},
      {month: 'February', days: 28},
      {month: 'March', days: 31},
      {month: 'April', days: 30},
      {month: 'May', days: 31},
      {month: 'June', days: 30},
      {month: 'July', days: 31},
      {month: 'August', days: 31},
      {month: 'September', days: 30},
      {month: 'October', days: 31},
      {month: 'November', days: 30},
      {month: 'December', days: 31}
];

monthSearched = 'April';

let a = Array.from(months, (value, index) =>value);

let b = a.find(value => {
  return value.month = monthSearched;
});
console.log(b);
```

or just change your

```
return value.month = monthSearched;
```

to

```
return value.month === monthSearched;
```

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks

Comment: @Sanjay please upvote and give the green check if it's what you where looking for

Comment: Marking as answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
let b = a.filter(value => {
  return value.month == month;
});
```

Before you were assigning. The above == compares.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a assignment instead of a comparison.
It should be

```
let b = a.filter(value => {
 return value.month == month;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let months= [
      {month: 'January', days: 31},
      {month: 'February', days: 28},
      {month: 'March', days: 31},
      {month: 'April', days: 30},
      {month: 'May', days: 31},
      {month: 'June', days: 30},
      {month: 'July', days: 31},
      {month: 'August', days: 31},
      {month: 'September', days: 30},
      {month: 'October', days: 31},
      {month: 'November', days: 30},
      {month: 'December', days: 31}
];

month = 'April';

let a = Array.from(months, (value, index) =>value);

let b = a.filter(value => {
  return value.month == month;
});
console.log(b);
```

You used `=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippat,

```js
let months= [
      {month: 'January', days: 31},
      {month: 'February', days: 28},
      {month: 'March', days: 31},
      {month: 'April', days: 30},
      {month: 'May', days: 31},
      {month: 'June', days: 30},
      {month: 'July', days: 31},
      {month: 'August', days: 31},
      {month: 'September', days: 30},
      {month: 'October', days: 31},
      {month: 'November', days: 30},
      {month: 'December', days: 31}
];

month = 'April';

let a = Array.from(months, (value, index) =>value);

let b = a.filter(value => {
  if(value.month == month){
  return value.month;
  }
});
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 let months= [
  {month: 'January', days: 31},
  {month: 'February', days: 28},
  {month: 'March', days: 31},
  {month: 'April', days: 30},
  {month: 'May', days: 31},
  {month: 'June', days: 30},
  {month: 'July', days: 31},
  {month: 'August', days: 31},
  {month: 'September', days: 30},
  {month: 'October', days: 31},
  {month: 'November', days: 30},
      {month: 'December', days: 31}
  ];

month = 'April';

let a = Array.from(months, (value, index) =>value);

let b = a.filter(value => {
  return value.month == month; // use == instead of = filter callback should return a boolean 
});
console.log(b);
```